# Transfer function gives infinite gas warning in remix

Tags: solidity, remix, address.transfer

If I use this simple payout contract in remix, it gives me a warning that the gas costs is infinite. Is this an intended behaviour?

```
contract Payout
{
    function payout() public {
        msg.sender.transfer(2);
    }
}
```

Context of this question: trying to debug my application and  gas costs could be possible problem source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the Solidity compiler says that the gas requirement of a function is infinite, it is not necessarily the case that that function cannot be executed. It just means that the compiler was not able to determine a maximum amount of gas needed.

I am not sure why it wasn't able to do so. As far as I can tell, it always produces this warning when you use `.transfer(...)`. It might be because calls to `.transfer(...)` can potentially fail and `revert()` the transaction.

You can usually safely ignore this warning, though it is a good idea to do what you did and find the line that is causing the warning.

Comment: great, but how do you estimateGas?